# How can I generate a Bcrypt hash from the Windows command line

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, bcrypt, xojo

I am writing a desktop app in [Xojo](http://xojo.com) for Windows 7. The Xojo language does not have an implementation of Bcrypt.

Is there a free Windows command line executable that will take a password as a string and return it's Bcrypt hash? That way I can bundle the command line tool with my Xojo app and call it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xojo has Bcrypt with some external code.  see the forum thread https://forum.xojo.com/8592-bcrypt